# Editing chrome.storage.local of another extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

How can I edit `chrome.storage.local` of a given Chromium extension, while the browser is running?

Possible solutions:

1. If the browser wasn’t running, I could edit LevelDB files in `~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings/` from a Python script or similar — but LevelDB cannot be opened by multiple processes.
2. Maybe I could create another very small extension that could edit other extensions’ `chrome.storage.local` with some permission? But I can’t find anything about that…

Comment: A devtools panel extension that's shown on another extension's page can do it like the Storage Area Explorer extension does. Otherwise the only method is to use chrome.debugger, which is quite convoluted and may require running chrome with a command line to allow silent connection to extensions' background pages. Maybe you can simply disable the extension, run the python script, and re-enable it (this can be automated via chrome.management and nativeMessaging).

Comment: I see. Thank you for the detailed comment. I’ll see if its IndexedDB file is closed after disabling it. Thanks!